# Joomla plugin to show the number of visitors

Tags: plugins, joomla, visitor-pattern

I am looking for a Joomla plugin that can help me in showing the number of visitors who have recently visited a specific article in my website.. can anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option was available for all articles. You have to enable hits form article options.

```
Aticle Manager --> Choose the article --> Article Options --> Show Hits(change to yes)
```

If you want to enable this option for all articles you can done by the following way...

```
Aticle Manager --> Options(top right side) --> Show hits (change to "show").


                                  (or)
```

http://www.tooljoom.com/downloads/plugins/article-hits

Use this plugin for displaying article hits but it was available for `Joomla 1.5` version.

Format:  `{hits}...{/hits}`

Comment: that didn't work for me..is there any other options ?

Comment: Hi i think you got this.... right?

Answer (score 1):

Use Plugin "Article Hits"...

display your article hits using {hits}...{/hits} inside the editor...

Comment: how can this plugin be used in joomlah ?

Comment: there is a problem that is using the article hits plugin i need to use {hits}...{/hits} inside the editor for each article, means that when ever a new article is added i need to insert in manually each time, is there a solution where the number of hits can be automatically showed when new articles is added ?